# CSS - Sticky div on horizontal scroll?

Tags: javascript, css, angular-material

I have a div containing a form like this:

[image]

The results table below is very wide, so horizontal scroll is needed.

> How can I make the form div sticky so that when I horizontally scoll
>   over the results the form stays on the top?

Only found documentation on vertical scroll with `position:sticky`, but nothing about horizontal scroll. Any advice will be welcome.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Add a scroll bar only for the table! Wrap your table with a div, and add properties,  `width: 96%` and also add `overflow: auto` for wrapped div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to wrap the table in the div with class name wrapper or any name you want and add these styles:

```
.wrapper { 
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```