# CSS "position: sticky" on horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to build a horizontal scroll with multiple content boxes that belong to one title. So I'd like the title to stay while the content scrolls past it, until the next section with a new title comes.

Here's what I was trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/kjo4duts/23/

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.scroll {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.item {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.scroll .item .title {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

.item .content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">

  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">
      Title 1
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">

    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">
      Title 2
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">

    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">

    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Is there a way to address the "position: sticky" property to the outer parent (*.scroll*)? Or is there a smooth way to do it in JavaScript?
I tried to change the HTML structure, but with Flexbox you need a container for each box to get a horizontal layout..

Thanks in advance!

Edit: For anyone with the same problem. The solution is to add a relative position to the outer parent and the change the HTML structure a bit.

See updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r2czqwn7/20/

Comment: yoo looking for [scroll snap](https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS - Sticky div on horizontal scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58128904/css-sticky-div-on-horizontal-scroll)

Comment: Parent (.scroll) has to be `position: relative` at first as you can check in your [modified pen](https://jsfiddle.net/u9v75obj/) but I would consider different structure (all contents with same title could be in same _div_) to stick it over multiple items.

Comment: Thanks @Jax-p 
The position relative was what I needed! If you like, you can post an answer and I will accept it.
I modified the HTML structure as you suggested and it works like a charm! [link](https://jsfiddle.net/r2czqwn7/20/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parent (*.scroll*) has to be `position: relative` at first as you can check  below but I would consider different structure (all contents with same title could be in same div) to stick it over multiple items.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.scroll {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.item {
  flex-flow: column;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.scroll .item .title {
  position: sticky;
  display: inline;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

.item .content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border: 3px solid green;
}


.item .content:first-child {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">
      Title 1
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <div class="content">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">
      Title 2
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <div class="content">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <div class="content">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```